# what wrong with policies in laravel 5.4?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I have a problem with authorization's policy in laravel 5.4. My code is shown below:

**ManagerPolicy.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Policies;

use App\Models\User;
use App\Models\Manager;
use Illuminate\Auth\Access\HandlesAuthorization;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class ManagerPolicy
{
    use HandlesAuthorization;

    public function view(Manager $manager)
    {
      echo 1;
      die;
      return $manager->hasAccess('manages.view');
    }
}
?>
```

**AuthServiceProvider.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;


use App\Models\Manager;
use App\Policies\ManagerPolicy;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\AuthServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;

class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * The policy mappings for the application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $policies = [
        'App\Model'  => 'App\Policies\ModelPolicy',
        Manager::class => ManagerPolicy::class
    ];

    /**
     * Register any authentication / authorization services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot(Gate $gate)
    {
        $this->registerPolicies($gate);
        //
    }
}
?>
```

**In my blade template view :**

```
 @can('view', App\Models\Manager::class)
        <li>
          <a href="{!! route('manages.index') !!}">
            <i class="fa fa-user-o"></i> <span> Manager </span>
          </a>
        </li>
      @endcan
```

When I run `die()` command in "ManagerPolicy@view", it's not working for me.

Comment: stupid question, have the `AuthServiceProvider.php` registered to `providers` under `/config/app.php`?

Comment: I have checked "/config/app.php" file , AuthServiceProvider.php still exists in this file.  What's wrong with me ?

Comment: next item to check, did you fired `composer dump-autoload` once the class are completed?

Comment: Yes, I have run "composer dump-autoload"  and no error is shown.

Comment: Have you attached the middleware? you need to use the `can:show,manager` middleware. That syntax may be not perfect, could be `view`. `manager` should be the name of the route param eg `/managers/{manager}`. There's also `$this->authorizeResource()` on the controller as another option.

Comment: I just create an authorization via Blade Templates , not using middleware here. Thanks for your reply , morph.

Comment: I think you need to pass the `$manager` in to the `@can()` instead of the FQCN

Comment: i have tried your way , but it still not work. I think the function "view" in ManagerPolicy.php file is not executed. Thank you again , morph.